# Encoding "\xaf" char results in 2 encoded characters

Tags: python, encoding, hex

I've just stumbled across the fact that if I try to encode the "\xaf" character i get an additional character in my bytes object. Meaning when i run this command:

```
print('\xaf'.encode())
```

I get the following result:

```
b'\xc2\xaf'
```

So I thought maybe its something that the print function is doing, so I opened up IDLE and tried just running the command by itself and seeing what the output will be but the character is still there:

[image: Picture of command run in IDLE]

I really don't understand why this additional character is popping up and I would be very thankfull if someone could explain it to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is how UTF-8 encoding works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) works. You can read more about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#encodings). So the main idea is that UTF-8 uses following rules to encode the string.

- If the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) is < 128, it’s represented by the corresponding
  byte value.
- If the code point is >= 128, it’s turned into a sequence of two,
  three, or four bytes, where each byte of the sequence is between 128
  and 255.

Your initial character has code point greater than `128`(does not fit with one byte), hence encoded with two bytes.

Note: You can use `ord` function to get the Unicode code point for a one-character string

```
>>> help(ord)
Help on built-in function ord in module builtins:

ord(c, /)
    Return the Unicode code point for a one-character string.
>>>
>>> ord('\xaf')
175
>>> list('\xaf'.encode())
[194, 175]
```

Comment: "does not fit with one byte" That's slightly misleading. ``\xaf`` does fit one byte, and is even valid as a byte literal. What it doesn't fit is one byte *with one bit used as a flag*, i.e. 7 bit for data (< 128 unsigned int) plus a bit indicating whether additional bytes carry data of the same glyph.